# TypeError: Product is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman

I encountered a bug from the tutorial (from 2018) I was watching, which creates an api allowing the user to post json objects in MongoDB. I am new to JavaScript so I don't understand the reasoning for the TypeError, but I am assuming that it has to do with the code used being outdated. I have two files for this project:

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/swag-shop');

var Product = require('./model/product');
var WishList = require('./model/wishlist');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.post('/product', function(request, response) {
    var product = new Product();  // TypeError: Product is not a constructor
    product.title = request.body.title;
    product.price = request.body.price;
    product.save(function(err, savedProduct) {
        if (err) {
            response.status(500).send({error:"Could not save product"});
        } else {
            response.send(savedProduct);
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Swag Shop API running on port 3000...");
});
```

model/product.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var product = new Schema({
    title: String,
    price: Number,
    likes: {type: Number, default: 0}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', product);
```

When submitting a post request on Postman, I keep getting the TypeError exception inside of server.js, and I have marked the line of the TypeError.

I tried to make sure all of my syntax was correct, and I also searched this error on Google. Obviously I don't have an explicit constructor in product.js, which is what different websites said were the most common causes for this error. I wasn't sure what to do.

Comment: Have you tried a debugger to look at the runtime value, to see what `Product` actually is?

Comment: Product was the import from the product.js file

Comment: Can you print what Product is after you require it from model? Seems like typeof Product is not a function.

Comment: I tried to print using console.log, but it's telling me that require is not defined? (line 1)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know reasoning of **Type Error** but the code you write is wrong.

You cannot directly change the values of `document` first you need to create `collection` and then using some functionality like `create`, `update` etc.

You have access to toggle data.

Reference -- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongoose-mongoose-model-function/

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. Why is the line "const collections = mongoose.model("GFG", collection_structure)" any different from what I did to export the Product objects on the product.js file?

Comment: in this case you have `data` but havent created any space to store. So first you have to create space in that collection and then store the document.